# Completar observações em um data frame

Tags: r, data.frame

Suponha que eu tenha o seguinte conjunto de dados:

```
dados <- structure(list(Ano = c(2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 
2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 
2005L), Categoria = structure(c(1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d"
), class = "factor"), Valor = c(15, 21, 15, 14, 18, 20, 17, 21, 
20, 23, 20, 22, 25, 18, 21, 16)), .Names = c("Ano", "Categoria", 
"Valor"), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = "data.frame")

dados
    Ano Categoria Valor
1  2001         a    15
2  2001         b    21
3  2001         d    15
4  2002         a    14
5  2002         c    18
6  2002         d    20
7  2003         a    17
8  2003         b    21
9  2003         c    20
10 2004         b    23
11 2004         c    20
12 2004         d    22
13 2005         a    25
14 2005         b    18
15 2005         c    21
16 2005         d    16
```

Este conjunto de dados possui 3 colunas: Ano, Categoria e Valor. Por definição, os anos vão de 2001 a 2005 e as únicas categorias possíveis são a, b, c, d. Entretanto, algumas categorias não foram registradas em alguns anos. Por exemplo, a categoria c não ocorreu em 2001. Por sua vez, a categoria b não ocorreu em 2002, e assim por diante.

Eu gostaria de criar um novo data frame com 5*4 = 20 linhas, pois este é o produto entre o número de anos e categorias distintos. Ou seja, o novo data frame deve ter todas as permutações possíveis entre cada valor de Ano e Categoria. O valor 0 deve ser designado para cada permutação que não existe no data frame original. Ou seja, desejo o seguinte resultado:

```
    Ano Categoria Valor
1  2001         a    15
2  2001         b    21
3  2001         c     0
4  2001         d    15
5  2002         a    14
6  2002         b     0
7  2002         c    18
8  2002         d    20
9  2003         a    17
10 2003         b    21
11 2003         c    20
12 2003         d     0
13 2004         a     0
14 2004         b    23
15 2004         c    20
16 2004         d    22
17 2005         a    25
18 2005         b    18
19 2005         c    21
20 2005         d    16
```

Como proceder de maneira automatizada para fazer isto?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Com o `tidyr` você pode usar a função `complete()`:

```
library(tidyr)
complete(dados, Ano, Categoria, fill = list(Valor = 0))
# A tibble: 20 x 3
     Ano Categoria Valor
   <int>    <fctr> <dbl>
 1  2001         a    15
 2  2001         b    21
 3  2001         c     0
 4  2001         d    15
 5  2002         a    14
 6  2002         b     0
 7  2002         c    18
 8  2002         d    20
 9  2003         a    17
10  2003         b    21
11  2003         c    20
12  2003         d     0
13  2004         a     0
14  2004         b    23
15  2004         c    20
16  2004         d    22
17  2005         a    25
18  2005         b    18
19  2005         c    21
20  2005         d    16
```

Answer (score 4):

Só com R base, pode-se usar `expand.grid`seguido de `merge`.

```
tmp <- expand.grid(Ano = unique(dados$Ano), Categoria = unique(dados$Categoria))

res <- merge(dados, tmp, all.y = TRUE)
res$Valor[which(is.na(res$Valor))] <- 0
res

rm(tmp)  # limpeza final
```